# Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise - Move Selected Lines Up / Down shortcut not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

For some users, including me, it seems that in Visual Studio 2017 (maybe only the Enterprise version) the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> does not work.

If you go to `Edit -> Advanced -> Move Selected Lines Up / Down` you can see if the shortcut is there or not.

[image]

If I go to `Tools -> Options... -> Environment -> Keyboard -> Edit.MoveSelectedLinesUp / Edit.MoveSelectedLinesDown` and assign <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> everything looks good from the edit view. However when I use the shortcut Visual Studio jumps between classes and methods in the file instead of moving the line. If I click on `Move Selected Lines Up / Down` from the menu the functionality works as expected. Why is this?

[image]

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/50611/move-line-updown-shortcut-doesnt-work.html

Comment: I see you have Resharper installed. My bet is some kind of key binding collision.

Comment: @Crowcoder I have `ReSharper` set to Visual Studio keyboard scheme. It should not steal any keybindings from VS features according to the documentation.

Comment: try disabling Resharper and see how it works.

Comment: @Crowcoder Tried with `Tools -> Options... -> ReSharper Ultimate -> Suspend` and it still does not work. Tried restarting VS with the feature suspended but the result was the same.

Comment: Tried the command from ReSharper which is `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+Up` and it worked with ReSharper enabled. So it definitely seems to be the culprit. To bad it seems I have to uninstall it for normal functionality to work.

Comment: Agreed. I used to use ReSharper but it made things so much worse because I was so trained on the default VS shortcuts. That and it brought VS to a crawl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by @Crowcoder `ReSharper` seems to be the culprit. Using the command  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> works. However suspending ReSharper via `Tools -> Options... -> ReSharper Ultimate -> Suspend` the normal command will still not work, even after restarting VS with the feature suspended. It seems ReSharper has to be uninstalled for this functionality to work again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found a way how it can work without uninstalling ReSharper for VS2019.

1. Tools -> Options -> ReSharper Ultimate -> Suspend
2. Extensions -> Manage Extensions -> Installed -> ReSharper -> Disabled
3. Rerun Visual Studio

To Enable Alt + Up arrow shortcuts you should reassigning shortcuts for ReSharper (TextEditor and XamlEditor) like on the image below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Every time I install Visual Studio with Resharper, I had this problem.

My Solution:

Go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard

Search for "Edit.MoveSelectedLines" and ensure that both commands are assigned with Alt+Up Arrow and Alt+Down Arrow respectively.

Search for ReSharper.ReSharper_GotoNextMember and remove the shortcut or give a new. It should  also be Alt+Down Arrow. Do the same for ReSharper.ReSharper_GotoPrevMember.